# how apply multiply file upload in controller code in php

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP and now doing a project in PHP. I want to upload images(maximum four image files only). I used the following code to upload images.

```
    public function news_upload()
    {

        //echo "hello";exit;
        $this->load->library('upload');
        //print_r ($_FILES);
         $_FILES['filename']['type']= $_FILES['filename']['type'];
         $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
         $_FILES['filename']['error']= $_FILES['filename']['error'];
         $_FILES['filename']['size']= $_FILES['filename']['size']; 
         $ext=pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
         //echo $ext;
         $_FILES['filename']['name'] = rand(0,1000)."_".strtotime("now")."_".rand(0,1000).'.'.$ext;

        //$document_file[] =  $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $this->upload->initialize($this->news_upload_options());
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
           $error = array('error' =>$this->upload->display_errors());    
        }
        else
        {
            $newstile=$this->input->post('news_title'); 
            $newsdate=$this->input->post('news_date'); 
            $uplo=$_FILES['filename']['name']; 
            $priority=$this->input->post('news_priority');
            $status=$this->input->post('news_status');
            $this->the_model->news_uploade($newstile,$newsdate,$uplo,$priority,$status);
        }
        redirect('welcome/discrp_news');

    }
```

I need help to modify this code to upload maximum of 4 images. Can rename function be used to rename a selected file for upload on moving to a specified folder? but it was showing error

Comment: it controller function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the file if files are multiple. Below is working example of mine .

```
function do_upload()
{       
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
    }
}

private function set_upload_options()
{   
    //upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './Images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

Hope it helps .